# Read-only file system error when trying to create MongoDB data directory in the root directory

Tags: mongodb, permissions

I recently downloaded MongoDB and moved it to the root directory on my Mac. However, when I try to create the data directory using the command `mkdir -p /data/db`, I encounter an error stating that the file system is read-only. How can I resolve this issue and successfully create the MongoDB data directory? I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

I tried to create a directory /data/db using the command `mkdir -p /data/db`. The expected outcome was the successful creation of the directory.
`arjunsingh@Arjuns-MacBook-Air ~ % mkdir -p /data/db              mkdir: /data: Read-only file system`

Comment: As far as I know the root directory is read/only. Choose another directory.

Comment: So how can i make the root to forcefully Create a  directory.

Comment: You should find a solution when you google for "mac root directory readonly" but I would really suggest to use a different folder, eg. `/usr/local/var/mongodb` You can freely configure it in Mongo config file.

Comment: How can i permanently set the path of mongod --dbpath

Comment: How do you start your MongoDB?

Comment: You cannot. Either start the MongoDB with `mongod --dbpath ...` or put it in a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and start the MongoDB with `mongod --config ...` the best option is to define mongod as a service, then it starts automatically at boot time.